# How to change the selection from one item to the selected item in tree control?

Tags: mfc, treecontrol

I had a tree control which is being populated some values.And In this few tree nodes consists of
check boxes whereas few doesn't. My problem is Initially when the tree is enumerated the default 
selection is on the first root node and this root node consists of three children where each child 
consists of check box. Here is my problem exactly is,

Now when I expand the tree and tried to click on the child item which consist of check box(clicking on the check box)
Until the mouse left button down the focus comes to the item we are checking and when the left button click up then 
the selection is reverting back to the root item (or to the item which is previously selected).

In order to resolve this this is something I tried,

```
 //TVN_ITEMCHANGED 
void CDriverSetupView::OnTvnItemChangedTree(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
NM_TREEVIEW* pNewTreeView = (NM_TREEVIEW*)pNMHDR;

if(NULL != pNewTreeView->itemNew.hItem)
{
   m_TreeCtrl.Select(pNewTreeView->itemNew.hItem,TVGN_CARET | TVGN_FIRSTVISIBLE | TVGN_DROPHILITE); 
   m_TreeCtrl.SelectItem(pNewTreeView->itemNew.hItem);
   m_TreeCtrl.SelectDropTarget(pNewTreeView->itemNew.hItem);
}

}
```

If I am doing like this then I am able to get the selection to whatever the child I am checking everything is cool.
But Initially when launch my application then the tree is is getting expanded and the selection is not on the root item
,it is moving on to the last item .

Please find the below images for better understanding,
When the tree is enumerated without the piece of code in OnTvnItemChangedTree,the tree looks like this,
[image]

Now when mouse left button down on the first checkbox the selection seems that it changed to checkbox
item ,

[image]

Now when mouse left button up on the checkbox the selection again revert back to the previous node,

[image]

Now when I use the piece of code within OnTvnItemChangedTree then I am able to get the selection to the checked node but initially when I launch my application then the tree is getting expanded and the selection is on to the last child item which is as follows,

[image]

In the above image I am able to get what I want but the tree is getting expanded and the selection is on to the last item,I know this is because in the `pNewTreeView->itemNew.hItem` at last after the initialization that item consists handle to the last item ,but how can we make such that initially the tree should not get expanded and selection should properly work when I check on any node then the selection should get changed to the checked item.

Can anyone please let me know how can make the selection to be remained on to the root item and the tree Initial status should 
be as not expanded.

Comment: And how you created the check boxes? With TVS_CHECKBOXES. When you remove all handler, there is no mystique focus Change in a tree control. So I can't understand your Problem. If you create check box Windows inside the tree Control you use a wrong approach.

Comment: I created a tree control with TVS_CHECKBOXES style.I will update my original post with images ,please kindly go through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it .In order to avoid that expand while at the time Initialization and moving the focus from one item to the checked item can be achieved as follows,

For `NM_CLICK` notification add this piece of code ,which works like charm.

```
void CMyTreeCtrl::OnNMClickTree(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    if(NULL != pNewTreeView->itemNew.hItem)
    {
        m_TreeCtrl.Select(pNewTreeView->itemNew.hItem,TVGN_CARET | TVGN_FIRSTVISIBLE | TVGN_DROPHILITE); 
        m_TreeCtrl.SelectItem(pNewTreeView->itemNew.hItem);
    }

}
```

The only mistake I had done was added this code in `OnTvItemChanged` Instead I added in `OnNMClickTree` ,Now finally I achieved what exactly I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably misunderstanding the question because the solution seems so obvious, but why don't you just collapse the tree and set the focus to the first item when you create it? So after you've added all children?

Comment: Where should I add collapse the tree is it in OnTvnItemChangedTree?If so this is being called every time I click on any item and the tree is getting collapsed and the focus is not on to the rootnode.Can you please help where should I collapse the tree.Should I add it in the same if condition of OnTvnItemChanged which I mentioned above.I added in the above condition like this ,m_TreeCtrl.Expand(m_TreeCtrl.GetRootItem(),TVE_COLLAPSE);
  m_TreeCtrl.SelectItem(m_TreeCtrl.GetRootItem());
  But it didn't work.Can you please help me to get rid off this problem.

Comment: Well after you populate it, presumably in OnInitDialog or so. What I understand from your question is that you populate the tree, do some stuff in OnItemChanged, and the stuff you do changes the selection. But you're asking about how to select a certain item right after the tree is initialized. So therefore my probably too simple answer 'then just set your selection back to what you want it to be right after you create and populate your tree'.